# Exporting data to excel in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, excel

I'm trying to export some data to an excel in my wordpress page, but when I save the file it print it on my browser and never open the dialog to save it.

I'm trying to save with this command.

```
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What headers are you sending with the response? Is there any whitespace at the beginning or end of the output you're generating?

Comment: Did you instantiate the `$objWriter` class first?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I instantiate it before.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel->workbook,'Excel5');
```

And I have use several headers, for example this one:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

And this too:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: Nobody can't help me?